# Регулярное выражение если часть строки может отсутствовать

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть строки следующего вида:

"M{A}{B}{C}", где

1. A- числа
2. B- пробелы; могут отсутствовать (если С отсутствует)
3. С- строки в скобках (т.е. вида "(текст_внутри_скобок)")

Каким регулярным выражением можно получить часть A, и текст внутри скобок части С?

*Примеры*:

```
| Строка                                | Результат                       |
|---------------------------------------|---------------------------------|
| "M01    (BlaBlaBla)"                  | ('01', 'BlaBlaBla')             |
| "M205         (BlaBlaBla blablablaa)" | ('205', 'BlaBlaBla blablablaa') |
| "M10"                                 | ('10', '')                      |
| "M190 (Текст внутри скобок)"          | ('190', 'Текст внутри скобок')  |
```

Я пользуюсь регулярным выражением `r'^M(\d+).*\((.*)\)'`, но данное выражение не работает, если отсутствует часть C и приходиться делать дополнительные проверки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте

```py
^M(\d+)(?:\s*\(([^()]*)\))?
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/iQzFUK/1).

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `M` - символ `M`
- `(\d+)` - Захватывающая подмаска №1: одна и более цифр
- `(?:\s*\(([^()]*)\))?` - необязательная незахватывающая подмаска:

  - `\s*` - ноль и более пробельных символов
  - `\(` - символ `(`
  - `([^()]*)` - Захватывающая подмаска №2: ноль и более символов, отличных от `(` и `)`
  - `\)` - символ `)`.

[Пример работы кода на Python](https://ideone.com/DrvU1O):

```py
import re
strings = ['M01    (BlaBlaBla)','M205         (BlaBlaBla blablablaa)','M10','M190 (Текст внутри скобок)']
rx = re.compile(r'^M(\d+)(?:\s*\(([^()]*)\))?')
for s in strings:
    m = rx.search(s)
    if m: print(m.groups())
```

Результат:

```py
('01', 'BlaBlaBla')
('205', 'BlaBlaBla blablablaa')
('10', None)
('190', 'Текст внутри скобок')
```